# How to get the event instances of a multi-day events using google calendar API?

Tags: node.js, google-api, google-calendar-api, google-api-js-client

I am working on a demo project where I need to fetch all events from the google calendar and show it in the home page.I am using gapi to fetch the events.

The properties for fetching has singleEvents as true and showDeleted as true.

I get all the events and instances of the recurring events as well.However the instances of a multiday event, for example an event that starts at Jan 1st and ends at Jan5th doesn't get replicated and I get only one event that has start date as Jan 1st. Could anyone suggest why the event instances of multi-day events are not being fetched?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is how Google Calendar works.   A single event has a start datetime and an end datetime.   There is only one event even though it occurs over several days.

If you want to retrieve multiple events you will need to insert an event for each time frame you are looking for.

Google is not going to spawn events for you it will only return the data it has.